# Fetch comma separated numbers by regex

Tags: regex, ruby

I need to fetch comma separated integers from a string of specific format using Ruby `String#match` method:

```rb
'text PaymentID: 12345'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1]          # expected result: ['12345']
'text Payment ID: 12345'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1]         # expected result: ['12345']
'text Payment id 12345'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1]          # expected result: ['12345']
'text paymentid:12345'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1]           # expected result: ['12345']
'text payment id: 12345'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1]         # expected result: ['12345']
'text payment ID: 111,999'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1]       # expected result: ['111', '999']
'text payment ID: 111, 222, 333'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1] # expected result: ['111', '222', '333']
```

So all spaces and ':' symbol are optional, the pattern should be case insensitive, text before `payment` can contain any characters.
My last variant was not good enough:

```rb
PATTERN = /payment[\s]?id[:]?[\s]?(\d+)(?:[,]?[\s]?(\d+))+/i

> 'text Payment id: 12345'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1]
=> ["1234", "5"]
> 'text Payment id: 12345, 333, 91872389'.match(PATTERN)[1..-1]
=> ["12345", "91872389"]
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not ``text.scan(/\d+/)``? Or maybe `text.scan(/(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,|payment\s?id:?)\s*\K\d+/i)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew text before the `payment` word can contain any characters, including digits. Question updated, sorry. I'll test the second regex, it looks suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```rb
text.scan(/(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,|payment\s?id:?)\s*\K\d+/i)
```

The regex matches

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,|payment\s?id:?)` - the end of the previous successful match and then zero or more whitespaces and a comma or `payment`, an optional whitespace, `id` and an optional colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\K` removes what has just been consumed from the match
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can't repeat a capture group since the last occurrence will overwrite the previous. What you can do is to use a `\G` based pattern that ensures the contiguity between successive matches with the scan method:

```
PATTERN = /(?:(?!\A)\G\s*,|payment\s*id\s*:?)\s*(\d+)/i

'text Payment id: 12345, 333, 91872389'.scan(PATTERN).flatten
```

In short the second branch `payment\s*id\s*:?` have to succeed first, to allow the first branch `(?!\A)\G\s*` to succeed for the next matches.